# What is significance of recovering the chaining value of a hash compression function?

Tags: hash

What is significance of recovering the chaining value of a compression function, when the message and its output are known? in other words, if a compression function $CF$ takes a chaining value $h_{in}$ and a message $m$ as inputs and outputs $h_{out}$.

$h_{out}=CF(h_{in}, m)$

Is it a bad property if given $m$ and $h_{out}$ to recover $h_{in}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be considered as a weakness of the compression function, which is not a *preimage resistant* anymore. Sometimes, but not always, this may imply an attack on a hash function or a larger construction using this compression function.

For instance, consider the **prefix** [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) scheme, which is constructed out of a hash function $H$ as follows:
$$
MAC_K(M) = H(K||M).
$$
The prefix scheme is secure for some hash functions, for example the SHA-3 (Keccak) hash function.

However, if the compression function used by $H$ is not preimage resistant, then an adversary given $MAC_K(M)$ may recover the chaining value
$$
CV=H(K),
$$
and construct a valid MAC for any other $M'$ even though he does not know $K$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see its relavence in this situation, but is recovering the chaining value and not the _message_ implies that the compression function is not _preimage resistant_? or like partially _invertable_. Does this property have a name?

Comment: Compression function squeezes its long input (possibly consisting of several shorter parameters) into a short output. If part of input can be recovered, it is not preimage-resistant, no matter where this part is located.